# Email messages doesn't reach Gmail mailbox when using SMPT

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

I have configures and `send.php` file to send mail messages using SMTP. When I use my website mailbox `$to = "info@my-site.com";`, I get messages to my mailbox. When I use gmail `$to = "email@gmail.com";` then I don't receive messages. I generated SMTP server password in Gmail App Passwords.
What can be reason?

```
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->isSendMail();
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;
$mail->Debugoutput = function ($str, $level) {
    $GLOBALS['status'][] = $str;
};

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Username = 'username';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
// Set up email
$to = "email@gmail.com";
$body = "From: $name\n Email: $email\n Message:\n $message";
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";

// Send email
// Set the email details
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress($to, 'Name');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
```

Here is a code piece responsible for settings.

Comment: Please add your code. Did you enable insecure apps in gmail?

Comment: @user3783243, Just added a code.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting